# Child index out of range, python element tree

Tags: python, elementtree

I am receiving an error I have never received before when trying to run this code.

`File "BasicEmail.py", line 96, in init_ui root[0][1].text
IndexError: child index out of range
Abort trap: 6`

My code is simple,

```
class EmailBlast(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        user_file = 'user_info.xml'
        tree = ET.parse(user_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        root[0][1].text
        self.emailLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Email:")
        self.emailListLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("")
        self.sendButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Save")
        self.settingsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Settings")

        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.emailLabel)
        v_box.addWidget(self.emailListLabel)
        v_box.addWidget(self.sendButton)
        v_box.addWidget(self.settingsButton)        
        v_box.addLayout(h_box)

        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setWindowTitle("Email Blast")

        self.settingsButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.settings(self.settingsButton, "Saved"))        
        self.show()

    def settings(self, settingsButton, string):
        self.ui = ConfigWindow()
        self.hide()        
        print("Settings")
```

I am able to get the tags and attributes, no values. The data in the XML is fine and there should be an array, or list, there for me to pull from.

Included full xml file:

```
<data>
<email>ewokhugz@gmail.com</email>
<password>testpass</password>
<smtp>gmail</smtp>
<port>587</port>
</data>`
```

Comment: check the result of `tree.getroot()`, with `print(len(tree.getroot()))` and `print(len(tree.getroot()[0]))`, it's hard to say what's wrong without more code

Comment: You could provide the .xml

Comment: @PRMoureu <Element 'data' at 0x104e40f98>
I will also provide the xml

Comment: @PRMoureu User info saved! 
4
0
Saved

Comment: the guilty line `root[0][1].text` does pretty much nothing as it's written, you need to assign the result ? otherwise you can comment or remove it

Comment: then if `print(len(tree.getroot()[0]))` returns 0, you have no chance to reach `root[0][1]`

Comment: @PRMoureu I'm aware. I am writing it like that only to show the problem that I need to solve. Simply access data in the xml. How do I make that not 0?

Comment: The problem is not caused by pyqt, so that tag is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data xml pattern presents the children directly inside the root,
so no need to access a nested child:

```
root = tree.getroot()
root[0].text # returns the email
root[1].text # returns the password
root[2].text # returns the smtp 
root[3].text # returns the port
```

You can also use the name query to allow some change in your pattern :

```
root.find('email').text
```