# Why am I getting child index out of range error when I writing to XML file in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a name in the list of a dictionary to XML file but I'm getting IndexError as child index out of range. I'm new to XML file. Here is my code

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
from xml.dom import minidom
name = [{'vehicle': 'honda'}, {'vehicle': 'hyundai'}, {'vehicle': 'mercedes'}, {'vehicle': 'rangerover'}, {'vehicle': 'bentley'}, {'vehicle': 'toyota'}, {'vehicle': 'mecerati'}, {'vehicle': 'lamborgini'}]
l = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
for step in range(10): 
            i,j = l[step]                      
            print(i,j)
            name1 = str(name[i]['vehicle'])
            root = Element('annotation')
            folder = SubElement(root, 'folder')
            folder.text="testing"
            filename=SubElement(root, 'filename')
            filename.text="1.jpg"
            path=SubElement(root, 'path')
            path.text="path"
            source=SubElement(root, 'source')           
            obj=SubElement(root, 'object')
            name=SubElement(obj,'name')
            name.text=str(name1)                                    
            tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
            tree.write(os.path.join('testing',str(step)+".xml"))
```

When second iteration occurs with the same i value it throws the error.

```
    0 1
    0 2
---> 10             name1 = str(name[i]['vehicle'])


IndexError: child index out of range
```

can you help me to figure out what wrong I'm doing and a  way to fix it? I found a similar question but it didn't fix my error [Child index out of range, python element tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575455/child-index-out-of-range-python-element-tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you do `name=SubElement(obj,'name')`, you are overwriting your original name list. Change that variable name to something else.